# How ot return 0 instead of null on mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following query returns the visitors and pageviews of last 7 days. However, if there are no results (let's say it is a fresh account), nothing is returned.

How to edit this in order to return 0 in days that there are no entries?

```
SELECT Date(timestamp)      AS day, 
       Count(DISTINCT hash) AS visitors, 
       Count(*)             AS pageviews 
FROM   behaviour 
WHERE  company_id = 1
       AND timestamp >= Subdate(Curdate(), 7) 
GROUP  BY day
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always have at least one record in the table for each of the last 7 days (regardless of the `company_id`), then you can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select 
    date(timestamp) as day, 
    count(distinct case when company_id = 1 then hash end) as visitors, 
    sum(company_id = 1) as pageviews 
from behaviour 
where timestamp >= curdate() - interval 7 day
group by day
```

Note that I changed you query to use standard date arithmetics, which I find easier to understand that date functions.

Otherwise, you would need to move the condition on the date from the `where` clause to the aggregate functions:

```
select 
    date(timestamp) as day, 
    count(distinct case when timestamp >= curdate() - interval 7 day and company_id = 1  then hash end) as visitors, 
    sum(timestamp >= curdate() - interval 7 day and company_id = 1) as pageviews 
from behaviour 
group  by day
```

If your table is big, this can be expensive so I would not recommend that.

Alternatively, you can generate a derived table of dates and `left join` it with your original query:

```
select
    curdate - interval x.n day day,
    count(distinct b.hash) visitors,
    count(b.hash) page_views
from (
    select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
) x
left join behavior b
    on  b.company_id = 1
    and b.timestamp >= curdate() - interval x.n day
    and b.timestamp < curdate() - interval (x.n - 1) day 
 group by x.n
```

Comment: If it is a newly created account, that means they will not have any data at all, even for that specific day...

Comment: @EnexoOnoma: yes I understand that. But does your table have data for that day (regardless of the `company_id`)? See my answer for different solutions according to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query that returns all the dates from today minus 7 days to today and left join the table behaviour:

```
SELECT t.timestamp            AS day, 
       Count(DISTINCT b.hash) AS visitors, 
       Count(b.timestamp)     AS pageviews 
FROM (
  SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 7) timestamp UNION ALL SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 6) UNION ALL 
  SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 5) UNION ALL SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 4) UNION ALL SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 3) UNION ALL 
  SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 2) UNION ALL SELECT Subdate(Curdate(), 1) UNION ALL SELECT Curdate()
) t LEFT JOIN behaviour b 
ON Date(b.timestamp) = t.timestamp AND b.company_id = 1
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: hi, this returns all results as 0, but I do have results in those days

Answer (score -2):

Use IFNULL:

> IFNULL(expr1, 0)

From the documentation:

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns >a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Answer (score -2):

You can use next trick:

1. First, get query that return 1 dummy row: `SELECT 1;`
2. Next use LEFT JOIN to connect summary row(s) without condition. This join will return values in case data exists on NULL values in other case.
3. Last select from joined queries onle what we need and convert NULL's to ZERO's 
   using IFNULL dunction.

   ```
   SELECT 
       IFNULL(b.day,0) AS DAY,
       IFNULL(b.visitors,0) AS visitors,
       IFNULL(b.pageviews,0) AS pageviews
   FROM (
       SELECT 1
   ) a
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP)      AS DAY, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT HASH) AS visitors, 
          COUNT(*)             AS pageviews 
       FROM   behaviour 
       WHERE  company_id = 1
          AND TIMESTAMP >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) 
       GROUP  BY DAY 
   ) b ON 1 = 1;
   ```